# PG Database works great on localhost but not on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a Rails app using Active record library. While on localhost, everything is getting saved corretly to the database. However, when the same code is uploaded to Heroku, and I click on the button that should save it to the database, I get the following error: **We're sorry, but something went wrong.**

From my logs I get the following error:
**ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "messages" does not exist**

Localhost database info:

```
     Name          |  Owner   | 
   messages        |  kari    |
```

How do I fix my database in Heroku.

Comment: You haven't yet migrated your database on Heroku, correct?

Comment: How do I migrate it?

Comment: You need to run your migration on the Heroku server too: `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to migrate your database.

You need to have the [Heroku command line interface (CLI)](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) installed.

Then, in console, you'll do something like:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

If you have more than one heroku remote defined (like, I tend to have heroku_staging and heroku_production), then it would be something like:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate --remote heroku_production
```

You can also do something like:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate --app your_app_name
```

If you prefer that.

Comment: But my heroku app is connected to a GitHub repo, how do I do this via the terminal(I have a local clone of the repo)

Comment: Like I said above, you need to have the Heroku CLI installed on your local machine and then you type one of those commands into your terminal.

Comment: I have it installed but my app is getting it's source code from Github, all I have is a local copy of repository so there is no heroku app stored on my PC.

Comment: There is no Heroku app stored on your local computer. If you want to deploy the code from your github account to Heroku you'll need to run `git push heroku master`

Comment: Well, not really. The app is deployed automatically whenever I push to the GitHub repo. and if I do a heroku login in the place where the code is storred locally(the github clone on my machine) and I try to run any command, I get the ** ▸    No app specified**

Comment: To specify an app, try that last line I gave you with the `--app` switch.

Comment: I get the following error: https://ibb.co/ifBcJ6
My code is:
     class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.text :text # add info  to database
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

Comment: Ugh. Code in comments. So yucky. But, best as I can tell, that looks ok. I guess if I were you I'd take that comment out just in case it's gumming up the works.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zbWFxknj
Here is the code, I removed the comment and the problem is still there.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with that. I suggest you start a new question and someone may know what's wrong.